# Updating app to swift, trying to display a percentage

Tags: ios, swift

I am updating my app for swift. I am trying to display a percentage once the "calculate" button is pushed.

So far I have:

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var calculated = (correctNumber / correctNumber + incorrectNumber * 100 )
        calculateLabel.text = "\(calculated)"



    }
```

Which I know is incorrect. How do I convert this to a percentage?

Full code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var correctNumber = 0
    var incorrectNumber = 0
    var verbalNumber = 0
    var visualNumber = 0
    var tactileNumber = 0




//rightnumber____________________________________

    @IBOutlet weak var correctLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func correctUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

        correctNumber += 1
        correctLabel.text = "\(correctNumber)"
    }

    @IBAction func correctDownButton(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        correctNumber -= 1
        correctLabel.text = "\(correctNumber)"

    }
//------------------------------------------------

//incorrectNumber________________________________

    @IBOutlet weak var incorrectLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func incorrectUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

        incorrectNumber += 1
        incorrectLabel.text = "\(incorrectNumber)"

    }

    @IBAction func incorrectDownButton(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        incorrectNumber -= 1
        incorrectLabel.text = "\(incorrectNumber)"

    }

//end-------------------------------------------------

//verbalNumber________________________________

    @IBOutlet weak var verbalLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func verbalUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

        verbalNumber += 1
        verbalLabel.text = "\(verbalNumber)"
    }

    @IBAction func verbalDownButton(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        verbalNumber -= 1
        verbalLabel.text = "\(verbalNumber)"
    }


//end-------------------------------------------------

//visualNumber________________________________

    @IBOutlet weak var visualLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func visualUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

        visualNumber += 1
        visualLabel.text = "\(visualNumber)"

    }

    @IBAction func visualDownButton(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        visualNumber -= 1
        visualLabel.text = "\(visualNumber)"

    }


//end-------------------------------------------------

//tactileNumber________________________________________

    @IBOutlet weak var tactileLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func tactileUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

        tactileNumber += 1
        tactileLabel.text = "\(tactileNumber)"

    }

    @IBAction func tactileDownButton(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        tactileNumber -= 1
        tactileLabel.text = "\(tactileNumber)"

    }


//end--------------------------------------------------

//calculate______________________________________________

    @IBOutlet weak var calculateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var calculated = (correctNumber / correctNumber + incorrectNumber * 100 )
        calculateLabel.text = "\(calculated)"



    }

//end----------------------------------------------------

    //reset
    @IBAction func resetButton(sender: UIButton) {

        correctNumber = 0
        correctLabel.text = ""
        incorrectNumber = 0
        incorrectLabel.text = ""
        verbalNumber = 0
        verbalLabel.text = ""
        visualNumber = 0
        visualLabel.text = ""
        tactileNumber = 0
        tactileLabel.text = ""
        calculateLabel.text = ""
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: By math laws your calculated variable become 1 + (incorrectNumber * 100) so idk maybe thats where your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly you need change line like this one:

```
var calculated = correctNumber / (correctNumber + incorrectNumber) * 100
```

Comment: Well I am going for a percentage correct vs. total so that wouldn't work. Thanks for the comment though.